# Jess engine.batch fails in jar package

Tags: java, jess

I would like to execute constructs file located under `src` directory from a java file using:

```
engine.batch("src/constructs.clp");
```

When I run the program by compiling in Eclipse I have no problem. However, when I create Runnable Jar by exporting, my program fails to execute `src/constructs.clp` file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is a part of the error message I get:

```
Jess reported an error in routine batch.

      Message: Cannot open file.
        at jess.Batch.findDocument(Unknown Source)
        at jess.Batch.batch(Unknown Source)
        at jess.Batch.batch(Unknown Source)
        at jess.Batch.batch(Unknown Source)
        at jess.Batch.batch(Unknown Source)
        at jess.Rete.batch(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program fails to execute because there is no src folder inside the jar. You can check by opening the jar by any unzip software like winrar.

The program should work if you put the constructs.clp file in same directory of the java program that uses it and then call engine.batch("constructs.clp");

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this is happening because the `src/constructs.clp` file isn't included in your JAR. It turns out that the `batch` command in Jess can actually find and load files from the class path if they're not found on the file system. If you package your `src/constructs.clp` file into the JAR, then the `batch` command will find it, and your code will work unchanged both in development and at runtime -- this is by design.